# Convert Flat File to Latex

Tags: bash, latex

I have been having an issue converting a flat text file into latex and getting printed out, using a bash script.

I have a file of this form.

```
Name|LastName|Number|Category

Col1|Col2|Col3|Col4
```

I want to print the file out when sorted by category and then last name on the category. I am able to use the sort command to get the file sorted correctly and I could print to the screen or a file using awk and printf, but I don't know how to convert it to latex. I have never used latex before and am unfamiliar with almost every aspect of it. The file should look something like this.

```
Name---------Last Name------Number--------Category

Col1-----------Col2--------------Col3-------------Col4
```

(Where the `'-'s` are simply blank space.)

Then I need to use LaTex to save the file as a PDF. Any assistance on this would be wonderful.

Comment: Your first task should be to develop some familiarity with LaTeX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following

```
% cat try.csv
four|five|six|cat1
one|two|three|cat3
seven|eight|nine|cat2
```

That's an input file which appears to be of the form you're describing.

```
% sort --field-separator=\| -k 4 try.csv | sed -e 's/|/\&/g' -e 's/$/\\\\/' >table-content.tex 
% cat table-content.tex 
four&five&six&cat1\\
seven&eight&nine&cat2\\
one&two&three&cat3\\
```

The `--field-separator` option says that we want vertical bar characters to separate the fields, and the `-k 4` option says we want to sort on field 4 (ie, the category column).  The output of that is sent into a sed script, which replaces each of the vertical bar characters by a `&` character (escaped as `\&` otherwise `sed` interprets that character as something else), and replaces the end of line (ie, `$`) with a `\\` string (each of these backslashes has to be escaped with a backslash, or, again, `sed` interprets it as something else).  The result is a file which is LaTeX's idea of a table: it has columns separated by the `&` character, and each line ended with `\\`.

Then we `\input` that into a LaTeX document:

```
% cat sorted.tex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

This is a table:

\begin{centering}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\input{content}
\end{tabular}\\
\end{centering}

\end{document}
```

You can search online for information on LaTeX.

Then run LaTex on this `sorted.tex` file:

```
% pdflatex sorted
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./sorted.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
... ... ...
Output written on sorted.pdf (1 page, 15286 bytes).
Transcript written on sorted.log.
%
```

...and the result is a PDF which has that table reasonably nicely formatted.

The `sed` command is slightly special, because you have to know a little bit of detail about how `sed`'s regular expression substitutions work (that is, the `s/from/to/` substitutions) and it's a bit of a gotcha that both the `&` and the `\\` that LaTeX requires have to be escaped here.  But otherwise this is just what `sort` and `sed` and friends are designed to be used for.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I believe this is enough to get me down the path I need!